# How do I check if a class has been used in another class within the same module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have a module which has multiple classes. One class, say A, is dependent on another, say B, *i.e.* A has a method which creates B's object and uses it. Note, there is no inheritance involved but just the simple fact that A is *dependent* on B.

I have been using a custom class named `ModuleUseCollector` and visit the source module file to check if a module has been used in another module. However, I have no idea how to check if a class has been used in another class of the same module.

Giving a minimal viable example:

```
class CarPollutionPermit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.permit = False

    def check_permit(self, year, mileage):
        if year < 2016:
            return False
        if mileage > 15:
            return True
        return False


class BikePollutionPermit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.permit = True

    def check_permit(self, year, mileage):
        if year < 2010:
            self.permit = False
            return False
        if mileage < 40:
            if year > 2016:
                return True
            self.permit = False
            return False
        self.permit = True
        return True


class TractorPollutionPermit:
    def fetch_tractor(self, year, is_farmer):
        if year > 2015 and is_farmer:
            return True
        if year > 2017:
            return True
        return False


class TractorPesticides(TractorPollutionPermit):
    def fetch_pesticides_permit(self, pesticide_effect):
        if pesticide_effect < 10:
            if self.fetch_tractor(2019, True):
                return True
            return False
        car_pollution_permit = CarPollutionPermit()
        return (car_pollution_permit.check_permit(2019, 16))
```

As you can see, the class `TractorPesticides` is dependent on `CarPollutionPermit`. I have to extract this relation.
The codebase is of Python3 and my code to execute this functionality is also in python3.

Comment: Why is `TractorPesiticides` inheriting from `TractorPollutionPermit`? Why are you getting a `CarPollutionPermit` for a tractor? Why is `CarPollutionPermit` a class in the first place if it has one method that doesn't look at `self` at all?

Comment: Thanks for your response @chepner!

It is all random but the main point is to get the dependency within a module.

Comment: You can just remove CarPollutionPermit class and test what exceptions are raised. In the stacktrace you can see from where in the source code it was called.

Comment: @Frank thanks. I am sorry but I am not looking for solutions that involve a change in the codebase. I am looking for solutions that generate the information from the source code w/o changing it.

Comment: So you want something like a class diagram that shows which class depends to another?

Comment: Yes. I will plot that in excel sheet but first, getting that diagram(info) is important. I am able to find inter-module dependencies but not intra-module(dependencies within the same module). Here, module being one `.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with [`abstract syntax tree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) of your module. Example that works at least with your module and shows that `TractorPesticides` depends on `CarPollutionPermit`:

```
import ast


with open('test.py') as f:
    data = f.read()
    module = ast.parse(data)
    classes = [
        obj
        for obj in module.body
        if isinstance(obj, ast.ClassDef)
    ]
    class_names = [obj.name for obj in classes]
    dependencies = {name: [] for name in class_names}
    for cls in classes:
        for node in ast.walk(cls):
            if isinstance(node, ast.Call):
                if isinstance(node.func, ast.Name):
                    if node.func.id != cls.name and node.func.id in class_names:
                        dependencies[cls.name].append(node.func.id)
    for class_name, dependency in dependencies.items():
        print(class_name, dependency)
```

Output:

```
CarPollutionPermit []
BikePollutionPermit []
TractorPollutionPermit []
TractorPesticides ['CarPollutionPermit']
```

Comment: Thank you @sanyash for your answer.
However, I have been using ast to do all the work until now(getting inter-module dependencies). I have no idea how to get the intra-module even using ast. Can you help me with that? To be precise, can you write the code for your last para? Or guide me towards it?

Comment: @AviralSrivastava OK, will edit my answer later with more code that is close to solve your problem.

Comment: I could not test it but as I can see, that is exactly what I need.

Thank you so much for your efforts. Also, if you think the question is precise and can lead someone who has the same problem statement, please upvote it. If not, please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava already upvoted. The title is clear and searchable imho. The detailed description in body is understandable, code example is complete. Everything is OK.